# CGAL demo in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt5, cgal

I am trying to compile a cgal demo called AABB_tree. I am not very good with Cmake so I have tried-

1. created a QtWidget project in QtCreator in D:\CC++\Qt\demo with qmake.
2. deleted the default generated files(mainwindow.h, mainwindow.ui, etc....)
3. Added the given demo files in my project and copied the Resources folder to demo directory.
4. copied the necessary third party libraries to demo directory.
5. After that my demo [image: directory] looks like this

My **.pro** files contains

```
QT       += core gui opengl svg

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++14

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

INCLUDEPATH += boost_1_80_0 \
               gmp_x64-windows-static\include \
               mpfr_x64-windows-static\include \
               CGAL-5.5\include


SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    MainWindow.cpp \
    Scene.cpp \
    Viewer.cpp \
    benchmarks.cpp

LIBS += -LD:\CC++\Qt\demo\gmp_x64-windows-static\lib -lgmp \
        -LD:\CC++\Qt\demo\mpfr_x64-windows-static\lib -lmpfr

HEADERS += \
    Color_ramp.h \
    MainWindow.h \
    Refiner.h \
    Scene.h \
    Viewer.h \
    types.h

FORMS += \
    MainWindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

RESOURCES += \
    AABB_demo.qrc
```

The main file contains

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <CGAL/Qt/resources.h>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <CGAL/Qt/init_ogl_context.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  CGAL::Qt::init_ogl_context(4,3);
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  app.setOrganizationDomain("inria.fr");
  app.setOrganizationName("INRIA");
  app.setApplicationName("AABB tree demo");

  // Import resources from libCGALQt (Qt5).
  CGAL_QT_INIT_RESOURCES;

  MainWindow mainWindow;
  mainWindow.show();
  QStringList args = app.arguments();
  args.removeAt(0);

  if(!args.empty() && args[0] == "--use-meta")
  {
    mainWindow.setAddKeyFrameKeyboardModifiers(::Qt::MetaModifier);
    args.removeAt(0);
  }

  Q_FOREACH(QString filename, args)
    mainWindow.open(filename);

  return app.exec();
}

#include "Scene.cpp"
#include "Scene_moc.cpp"
#include "benchmarks.cpp"
#include "Viewer.cpp"
#include "Viewer_moc.cpp"
#include "MainWindow.cpp"
#include "MainWindow_moc.cpp"
```

The [image: problem] is that the demo does not include the following source files

1. Scene_moc.cpp
2. Viewer_moc.cpp
3. MainWindow_moc.cpp
4. ui_ImageInterface.h

Is it on the user to construct those files? Is there any complete demo or example available?

Comment: Try running `qmake` before building the project.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: images help clarify the problem. I cannot share the project file. I have included the code that is unique to my problem. The rest of the code is available in cgal official github repository. So if anyone want to regenerate the project can do with ease. I did not included the images for replacing code. They just shows the error list and setup which is difficult to explain by writting.

Comment: Even if you are not "very good in cmake"; it is probably simpler to use cmake. You only need to run cmake then make; and the demo is compiled. See this manual https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/usage.html